# combining groups of columns with boolean values to create multiple new columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, list-comprehension

I was wondering how I can create new columns based on old ones by multiplying two groups of them in my dataframe. So if I have [A, B] and [X, Y]:

```
   A     B      X     Y
0  True  False  True  False
```

Now I want this to result in 4 extra columns, of which only the one that has both true is true:

```
   A     B      X     Y      AX     BX      AY     BY
0  True  False  True  False  True   False   False  False
```

In my situation, the groups are bigger, so I'm looking for a solution that can be used by using the two lists of column headers [A, B] and [X, Y]. I have tried list comprehension but I cannot get it to work :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to get the cartesian product of column names then use [`Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) inside a list comprehension to create corresponding column products, finally use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat these products with `df`:

```
from itertools import product

l1, l2 = ['A', 'B'], ['X', 'Y']

c = [df[a].mul(df[b]).rename(''.join([a, b])) for a, b in product(l1, l2)]
df = pd.concat([df] + c, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
      A      B     X      Y    AX     AY     BX     BY
0  True  False  True  False  True  False  False  False
```

Comment: Amazing how fast you came up with that. Thank you! I could use this quite often!

Comment: Happy coding :) @Charles